# Update subset of values from one column based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` :-

| Store_id | fruit | region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange | x |
| 2 | apple | y |
| 3 | NotKnown | z |
| 5 | Notknown | q |
| 6 | banana | w |

I have a dataframe `df2` :-

| Store_id | fruit | region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange | x |
| 2 | apple | y |
| 3 | pears | z |
| 5 | strawberry | q |
| 6 | banana | w |
| 8 | mango | i |

Expected `df1` :-

| Store_id | fruit | region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange | x |
| 2 | apple | y |
| 3 | pears | z |
| 5 | strawberry | q |
| 6 | banana | w |

`Store_id` is the primary key.
How do I update column `fruit` of `df1` based on `df2` column `fruit` for value `NotKnown` under `fruit` column of `df1`

Comment: the question is unclear, what if you have a different fruit for the same id? several? a non-matching region?

Comment: Could you elaborate what is unclear?

Comment: Everything. You provide no logic at all, this makes any answer dependent on the interpretation of the answerer…

Comment: I have emaborated let me know if i makes sense now?

Comment: Then @Mustafa's answer should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
reg_to_fru = df2.set_index("region")["fruit"]
df1.fruit  = df1.region.map(reg_to_fru)
```

you can form a mapper (a Series) from `df2` as region -> fruit, then map the region in `df1` with it:

```py
In [39]: reg_to_fru = df2.set_index("region")["fruit"]

In [40]: reg_to_fru 
Out[40]:
region
x        orange
y         apple
z         pears
q    strawberry
w        banana
i         mango
Name: fruit, dtype: object

In [41]: df1.fruit = df1.region.map(reg_to_fru)

In [42]: df1
Out[42]:
   Store_id       fruit region
0         1      orange      x
1         2       apple      y
2         3       pears      z
3         5  strawberry      q
4         6      banana      w
```

Comment: Where are we replaving `NotKnown` under `fruit` column in this approach?

Comment: When `.map`ping. I assumed other values are by definition are the same in the other dataframe under region -> fruit mapping, so they get mapped, too. Like region "z" is looked up in `df2` and fruit is "pears", so that's put in `df1`. But also, region "x" is looked up as well, and its fruit "orange" is put as well (which was orange anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```py
df1['fruit'] = (df1['fruit'].str.lower().replace('notknown', pd.NA)
                .fillna(df1.merge(df2, on=['Store_id', 'region'], how='left')['fruit_y']))
```

```
print(df1)

   Store_id       fruit region
0         1      orange      x
1         2       apple      y
2         3       pears      z
3         5  strawberry      q
4         6      banana      w
```